# spy.and.throwError() - throw error as object?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, jasmine-node

is there any way to throw an error as an object in jasmine? In my productive code i use the error object (that comes from request promise native) to log some information. And then i have a logger spy, that checks if the error was logged correctly. But when my test throws the error with a simple error message and my productive code wants to access err.response.headers i get a runtime error.

i already tried to use it like this

```
spy.and.throwError(new Error({...}))
```

But as the constructor from Error only takes a string as argument, it obviously does not work

Answer (score 0):

`spy.and.returnValue(Promise.reject({message: 'someError', response: {headers: 'abc'}}));`

solved the problem